# Adobe Air Reflection through ANEs

Tags: java, reflection, air, invocationtargetexception, ane

So, I have an ANE (we call it `Leader ANE`) that I am accessing with reflection from another ANE (we call it `Follower ANE`) through Java. The idea is to have `Leader ANE` be able to function completely naturally without the need for `Follower ANE`, but if `Follower ANE` exists, it would alter its flow. This is easily done in Java using Reflection.

I have two `Follower ANE`s: `Leader ANE` is finding the first one through reflection with no issues.

The second one however, is giving me an `InvocationTargetException` whenever I call `invoke()` method. Does that mean that there was an exception occurring inside `Follower ANE`?

Has someone had or seen this use case before?

Comment: Can you illustrate some code of what you are doing? Might help to see what the issue is.